# PCL Outlier Filtering Huge Performance Difference Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: c++, openmp, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to filter a point cloud with 1 600 000 points using pcl::RadiusOutlier of PCL Library 1.8.1.

The code is as follows:

```
    pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> 
    radius_outlier_removal;
    radius_outlier_removal.setInputCloud(inCloud);
    radius_outlier_removal.setRadiusSearch(radius); 
    radius_outlier_removal.setMinNeighborsInRadius(requiredNeighbours);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    radius_outlier_removal.filter(*result);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    cout << "Filtering took " << duration << " seconds." << endl;
```

The output on Microsoft Visual Studio (debug mode) with enabled Open MP Support.

```
Filtering took 208 seconds.
```

Ubuntu 18.04 output, also built with enabled debug mode, same library version as Windows one:

```
Filtering took 4 seconds.
```

I've searched for other threads and any documentation into why the performance could be so different but couldn't find anything. The most I could find is to make sure that OpenMP is enabled when compiling, which I made sure to enable in Visual Studio.

I would appreciate any pointers into why Windows execution is so slow and how to boost its performance.

Comment: Don't trust any performance measurement with debug mode.

Comment: We need to see the compilation switches (both platforms) and performance measurements should be done in release mode.

Comment: By building the application in Release mode the performance is now as fast as in Ubuntu! Thank you!